# django count instances in a model

Tags: django, count, analytics

I have a model **ItemAdded**  and i made a signal so every time a user add an item to the cart  an instance is created in the **ItemAdded** model   so what i want to  do is count the most added items (in an ascending order) , so what is the easiest way to do this ??
this is the model :

```
class ItemAdded(models.Model):
user                = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # User instance instance.id

content_type        = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # User, Product, Order, Cart, Address
object_id           = models.PositiveIntegerField() # , Product id, 
content_object      = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id') # Product instance
timestamp           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)



def __str__(self):
    return "%s added on %s" %(self.content_object, self.timestamp)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-timestamp'] # most recent saved show up first
    verbose_name = 'Object added'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Objects addded'
```

Comment: do you care about the timing of the event for example will you store statistics about most added item in particular year/month or can you store plain absoulte number without any additional metadata?

Comment: @quqa123 no i don't care about the timing  ,i care about   the most added items ,maybe add a filtering system after   to filter the most added items by category ,type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about timing creating a separate model and thousands of database rows along you can simply create an `IntegerField` in your model which you will increment whenever you get the signal that you mentioned. To get the result:

**models.py**

```
class YourItemModel(models.Model)

     # YourItemModel attributes
     ...
     added_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0) # yes zero is accepted
```

Your signal logic:

```
from django.db.models import F

instance.added_count = F(added_count) + 1
instance.save()
```

The F object is preferred as it eliminates racing condition when we deal with a lot of calls. You can read about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions)

PS the `PositiveIntegerField` accepts value of 0 due to reverse compatibility reasons

Comment: Thank you  it's actually a good idea ; i 'll keep  the ItemAdded model for an other use  maybe notifications